# Localizing an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, localization

I developed a namedays and birthdays reminder application called Eortes. There is also a free  version of it called Eorteslite. The language as well as the namedays are in greek. More info here: http://sites.google.com/site/eortesapp/
I would like to localize these applications in other languages as well.
1) Where can I find other foreign developers willing to localize my application in their own language in exchange of localizing their application in greek. 
2) Does it need a considerable amount of programming time and skills to localize an iPhone app. I haven't done it before.
3) Are there any tools that could help me to this task?
Sincerely,
Nikos

Answer (score 0):

The Apple documentation on [Localization](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/LocalizingNibFiles/LocalizingNibFiles.html) is a good place to start.

Also, [this service](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) can perform some translation for you.  I've not used it myself yet, but may do in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the service.